# Web scraping nested divs with BeautifulSoup]

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape the content of the following website:

https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnys/mmm/quote.html

From there I want to click on **Executive**, then **Board of Directors**, and then I want to scrape the *Biography* from the **Profile** of each director. Ideally, the final result would have the Biography of each of the 12 members of the Board of Directors.
[Board of Directors Member Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2zcQ.png)

I am trying to do that with BeautifulSoup but I can't reach that nested div.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re, time
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
def get_directors(_html):
  _names = [i.text for i in soup(_html, 'html.parser').find_all('div', {'class':'name ng-binding'})]
  return _names[_names.index('Compensation for all Key Executives')+1:-1]

_board = {}
d = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/tS0u/Downloads/chromedriver')
d.get('https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnys/mmm/quote.html')
time.sleep(5)
_exec = d.find_elements_by_class_name("mds-button")
_exec[8].click()
time.sleep(3)
d.find_element_by_link_text("Board of Directors").click()
time.sleep(3)
full_directors = d.find_elements_by_class_name('person-row')[19:31]
for _name, _link in zip(get_directors(d.page_source), full_directors):
   _link.click()
   time.sleep(3)
   d.find_element_by_link_text("Profile").click()
   time.sleep(3)
   _board[_name] = soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser').find_all('div', {'class':'biography'})[-1].text
   _link.click()
   time.sleep(3)
   print(_board)
   with open('filename.csv', 'w') as f:
      write = csv.writer(f)
      write.writerows([['name', 'biography'], *map(list, _board.items())])
```

Making use of selenium and following @Ajax1234 I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/tS0u/Desktop/morningstar_stackoverflowanswer.py", line 21, in <module>
d.find_element_by_link_text("Profile").click()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 314, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: 
Element <a href="#" ng-click="subTab.tabSelect(tabItem, $event, item)" 
data-linkbinding="profile" class="ng-binding" label- 
short="...">Profile</a> is not clickable at point (57, 595). Other 
element would receive the click: <div id="_evidon_banner" 
class="evidon-banner" style="position: fixed; display: flex; align- 
items: center; width: 100%; background: rgb(239, 239, 239); font-size: 
14px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); z-index: 2147000001; padding: 10px 0px; 
font-family: UniversNextMorningStarW04, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
border-top: 2px solid rgb(153, 153, 153); bottom: 0px;">...</div>
(Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.77)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600229 
(3fae4d0cda5334b4f533bede5a4787f7b832d052),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)
```

The error when trying to export in csv

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/tS0u/Desktop/morningstar_stackoverflowanswer.py", line 22, in <module>
d.find_element_by_link_text("Profile").click()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 314, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: 
Element <a href="#" ng-click="subTab.tabSelect(tabItem, $event, item)" 
data-linkbinding="profile" class="ng-binding" label- 
short="...">Profile</a> is not clickable at point (57, 595). Other 
element would receive the click: <div id="_evidon_banner" 
class="evidon-banner" style="position: fixed; display: flex; align- 
items: center; width: 100%; background: rgb(239, 239, 239); font-size: 
14px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); z-index: 2147000001; padding: 10px 0px; 
font-family: UniversNextMorningStarW04, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
border-top: 2px solid rgb(153, 153, 153); bottom: 0px;">...</div>
```

Either way, I greatly appreciate the time spent to resolve my problem.

Comment: If the content you intend to scrape is triggered by a javascript action then you might want to make use of scraper or selenium instead to enable you perform operations such as clicking.

Comment: Just checked now, you'll need to make use of scrapy or selenium to scrape. This should help get you started: https://medium.com/@hoppy/how-to-test-or-scrape-javascript-rendered-websites-with-python-selenium-a-beginner-step-by-c137892216aa

Answer (score 0):

The site is dynamic, thus, you will have to use a browser manipulation tool such as `selenium`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re, time
from selenium import webdriver
def get_directors(_html):
  _names = [i.text for i in soup(_html, 'html.parser').find_all('div', {'class':'name ng-binding'})]
  return _names[_names.index('Compensation for all Key Executives')+1:-1]

_board = {}
d = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
d.get('https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnys/mmm/quote.html')
time.sleep(5)
_exec = d.find_elements_by_class_name("mds-button")
_exec[8].click()
time.sleep(3)
d.find_element_by_link_text("Board of Directors").click()
time.sleep(3)
full_directors = d.find_elements_by_class_name('person-row')[19:31]
for _name, _link in zip(get_directors(d.page_source), full_directors):
   _link.click()
   time.sleep(3)
   d.find_element_by_link_text("Profile").click()
   time.sleep(3)
   _board[_name] = soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser').find_all('div', {'class':'biography'})[-1].text
   _link.click()
   time.sleep(3)

print(_board)
```

Output (shortened to save space):

```
{'Inge G. Thulin': '\nBiography\n\n                Mr. Thulin is the Chairman of the Board, President and Chief Executive Officer of 3M Company. Mr. Thulin served as President and Chief Executive Officer of 3M Company from ....', 'Sondra L. Barbour': '\nBiography\n\n                Ms. Barbour is Executive Vice President, Information Systems and Global Solutions, Lockheed Martin Corporation, a high technology aerospace and defense company. Since joini....', 'Thomas K. Brown': '\nBiography\n\n                Mr. Brown is the Retired Group Vice President, Global Purchasing, Ford Motor Company, a global automotive industry leader. Mr. Brown served in various leadership capacities....', 'David B. Dillon': '\nBiography\n\n                —\n            \n....', 'Michael L Eskew': '\nBiography\n\n                Mr. Eskew is the Retired Chairman of the Board and Chief Executive Officer, United Parcel Service, Inc., a provider of specialized transportation and logistics services. Mr....', 'Herbert L. Henkel': '\nBiography\n\n                Mr. Henkel is the Retired Chairman of the Board and Chief Executive Officer, Ingersoll-Rand plc, a manufacturer of industrial products and components. Mr. Henkel retired as....', 'Amy Hood': "\nBiography\n\n                On August 13, 2017, the Board of Directors of 3M Company elected Amy E. Hood to the Company's Board of Directors, effective August 13, 2017. At Microsoft, Hood is responsib....", 'Muhtar Kent': "\nBiography\n\n                Mr. Kent is the Chairman of the Board and Chief Executive Officer, The Coca-Cola Company, the world's largest beverage company. Mr. Kent has held the position of Chairman o....", 'Edward M. Liddy': '\nBiography\n\n                Mr. Liddy is the Retired Chairman of the Board and Chief Executive Officer, The Allstate Corporation, and former Partner at Clayton, Dubilier & Rice, LLC, a private equity ....', 'Dambisa F. Moyo': "\nBiography\n\n                On August 12, 2018, the Board of Directors of 3M Company elected Dambisa F. Moyo to the Company's Board of Directors, effective August 12, 2018. Dr. Moyo is the founder and....", 'Gregory R. Page': "\nBiography\n\n                On February 1, 2016, the Board of Directors of 3M Company elected Gregory R. Page to the Company's Board of Directors, effective February 1, 2016. Page previously was Cargi....", 'Patricia A. Woertz': "\nBiography\n\n                On February 1, 2016, the Board of Directors of 3M Company elected Patricia A. Woertz to the Company's Board of Directors, effective at the close of business on February 2, ...."}
```

Edit:

Writing the results to `csv`:

```
import csv
with open('filename.csv', 'w') as f:
  write = csv.writer(f)
  write.writerows([['name', 'biography'], *map(list, _board.items())])
```

To create a more generic solution to handle different urls (possibly created from content in a list):

```
def scrape_bios(_driver:webdriver, _url:str) -> dict:
  _driver.get(_url)
  time.sleep(5)
  _exec = _driver.find_elements_by_class_name("mds-button")
  _exec[8].click()
  time.sleep(3)
  _board = {}
  _driver.find_element_by_link_text("Board of Directors").click()
  time.sleep(3)
  full_directors = _driver.find_elements_by_class_name('person-row')[19:31]
  for _name, _link in zip(get_directors(_driver.page_source), full_directors):
    _link.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    _driver.find_element_by_link_text("Profile").click()
    time.sleep(3)
    _board[_name] = soup(_driver.page_source, 'html.parser').find_all('div', {'class':'biography'})[-1].text
    _link.click()
    time.sleep(3)
  return _board
```

Now, you can loop over a listing of urls:

```
d = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
for url in urls:
  _results = scrape_bios(d, url)
```